# Add JavaScript code to an HTML page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, appendchild

I have an HTML form that takes field values to outputs custom instructions HTML & JavaScript instructions.

When the user fills the form and submits, JS code executes to inject the instructions at the bottom of the page. As soon as I include the `<script>`, the script "dies" and the button stops working. I don't understand what is going on.

Below is my code. Let me know if you need anything else.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function formInfo(personalCode)
        {
            var instructionHttp = "<p># Step 1 - Add " + personalCode + "'s API</p><pre><script src='https://" + personalCode + ".customapi.com'></script></pre>";
            document.getElementById('returnedHtml').innerHTML = instructionHttp;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Instructions Generator</h1>
    <form name="myform" action="" method="GET">
        <div class="showLabel"><label for="signupcode">Code</label></div><input type="text" name="signupcode" value="" autofocus ><br>
        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="
            code=document.myform.signupcode.value;
            formInfo(signupcode);"> <br>
    </form>
    <br><hr><br>
    <p>--- Customized Instructions ---</p>
    <br>
    <div id="returnedHtml"></div><br>
</body>
```

I have also tried replacing formInfo() with the following

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function formInfo(personalCode)
        {
            var pre1 = document.createElement('pre');
            var api = document.createElement('script');
            api.src = "https://" + personalCode + ".customapi.com";
            pre1.appendChild(api);

            var instructionHttp = "<p># Step 1 - Add " + personalCode + "'s API</p>";
            instructionHttp.appendChild(pre1);

            document.getElementById('returnedHtml').innerHTML = instructionHttp;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to create html from string and just append to element, it's wrong, you must create elements as you did with `script` and `pre`.

This code will work for you:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function formInfo()
            {
               var personalCode = document.getElementById('signupcode').value
               var pre1 = document.createElement('pre');
               var api = document.createElement('script');
               api.src = "https://" + personalCode + ".customapi.com";
               pre1.appendChild(api);

               var instructionHttp = document.createElement('p');
               instructionHttp.innerHTML = "# Step 1 - Add " + personalCode + "'s API"

               instructionHttp.appendChild(pre1);

               document.getElementById('returnedHtml').innerHTML = instructionHttp.outerHTML;
           }
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <h1>Instructions Generator</h1>
       <form name="myform" action="" method="GET">
           <div class="showLabel"><label for="signupcode">Code</label></div><input type="text" name="signupcode" id="signupcode" value="" autofocus ><br>
           <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="formInfo()"> <br>
       </form>
       <br><hr><br>
       <p>--- Customized Instructions ---</p>
       <br>
       <div id="returnedHtml"></div><br>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes more sense than what I was doing. However, the `script` is being loaded rather than being printed, which is what I expect when placing it in a `pre` element. Any suggestions?

Comment: Resolved by adding `pre1.textContent = api.outerHTML;`, rather than appending.

Answer (score 0):

You can not create an element with HTML; you can only create an element by its tag name (you can set its text with the `textContent` attribute) to append to a DOM element.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function formInfo(personalCode)
        {
            //var pre1 = document.createElement('pre');
            var api = document.createElement('script');
            api.src = "https://" + personalCode + ".customapi.com";
            //pre1.appendChild(api);
         
            var instructionHttp = "<p></p>";
            var instructionHttp = document.createElement("p");
            instructionHttp.textContent = "# Step 1 - Add " + personalCode + "'s API";
            instructionHttp.appendChild(api);

            document.getElementById('returnedHtml').innerHTML = instructionHttp.innerHTML;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Instructions Generator</h1>
    <form name="myform" action="" method="GET">
        <div class="showLabel"><label for="signupcode">Code</label></div><input type="text" name="signupcode" value="" autofocus ><br>
        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="
            code=document.myform.signupcode.value;
            formInfo(code);"> <br>
    </form>
    <br><hr><br>
    <p>--- Customized Instructions ---</p>
    <br>
    <div id="returnedHtml"></div><br>
</body>
</html>
```